# Symfony admin generator datetime picker

Tags: php, jquery, symfony1, admin

How can I use a jQuery datetime picker in the symfony admin generator?

Answer (score 1):

Get the [sfFormExtraPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfFormExtraPlugin) and download the third-party libraries that the plugin uses (like jQuery, jQuery UI) yourself. The rest should be described on the site I linked to check the "Readme"-tab and the links in there.

Answer (score 0):

Admin use symfony forms so the simplest way is to use datepicker widget there and it will be used automatically in generated administration. You can create the widget by yourself or extract it from sfFormExtraPlugin suggested by *jitter*.

Answer (score 0):

sfFormExtraPlugin doesn't have a datetime picker. It has a "date picker". This seems not to be of importance but actually is.